# Error "too many variables in range" when iterating over a channel

Tags: for-loop, go, channel

I'm kind of lost here, I was trying to get a goroutine to add to an array and another goroutine to read from it, which I suspect is somewhat close to what I have below but I need to play around with the wait().

However, I am getting the error `prog.go:19:14: too many variables in range`, line 19 is `for _, v := range c {` I can't find an answer for that online, what am I doing or not doing here?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    //"time"
    "sync"
)

func hello(wg *sync.WaitGroup, s []int, c chan int) {
    for _, v := range s {
        c <- v
    }
    fmt.Println("Finished adding to channel")
    wg.Done()
}

func hello2(wg *sync.WaitGroup, c chan int) {
    fmt.Println("Channel",c)
    for _, v := range c {
        fmt.Println("Received",v)   
    }
    fmt.Println("Finished taking from channel")
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    var c = make(chan int, 5)


    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go hello(&wg, s, c)
    wg.Wait()
    wg.Add(1)
    go hello2(&wg, c)
    wg.Wait()
    //time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("main function")
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you range over a channel, iterations only produce a single value, the values that were sent on the channel. There is no index or key value like in case of slices or maps.

So you must use:

```
for v := range c {
    fmt.Println("Received", v)   
}
```

This is detailed in [Spec: For statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)

> **If the range expression is a channel, at most one iteration variable is permitted**, otherwise there may be up to two.

And:

> For channels, the iteration values produced are the successive values sent on the channel until the channel is [closed](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close). If the channel is `nil`, the range expression blocks forever.

And also:

> Function calls on the left are evaluated once per iteration. For each iteration, iteration values are produced as follows if the respective iteration variables are present:
>
> ```
> Range expression                          1st value          2nd value
>
> array or slice  a  [n]E, *[n]E, or []E    index    i  int    a[i]       E
> string          s  string type            index    i  int    see below  rune
> map             m  map[K]V                key      k  K      m[k]       V
> channel         c  chan E, <-chan E       element  e  E
> ```

Comment: So even when using `_`, its still expecting that value to be returned, even though its going to be thrown away?

Comment: @Derek Yes, if you specify the blank identifier, that means you are expecting 2 values in each iterations, yet ranging over a channel only produces 1.

Answer (score 0):

I know you were not intending/wishing to use an iterator for your channel for range loop, but **if you do wish to have an iterator it is still possible** via defining the iterator yourself outside of the loop and incrementing it each time a value in the channel is read.

```
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var iterator = 0
    for v := range c1 {
        wg.Add(1)
        iterator += 1
        go func(v2, i2 int) {
            c2 <- timeConsumingWork(v2)
            fmt.Println("item ", i2, " done")
            wg.Done()
        }(v, iterator)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(c2)

}
```

Here you can see the go func is accepting the channel value(v2) and the iterator value(i2), while incrementing it each time a value is read from the channel.

Additionally I see you used buffered Waitgroups to avoid blocking with the sequential calling of your two methods.  Ideal Go code should avoid buffered channels whenever possible and instead call the sending and receiving functions in an interlocked fashion so that they do not need be seperated.